# Encrypting Connection Strings in Config File Used on Multiple Machines C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption, connection-string

At the moment I am storing my connection strings in my app.config file in plain text. Bad practice, I know, and I am trying to encrypt them instead. I've referred to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx and haven't had an issue with getting the app.config part working on my machine.

My connection strings now look like this (I've left the cipher value out);

```
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue></CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
```

My issue is when I come to use this on another machine. As the config file they are using has come from my machine, only my machine can decrypt the connectionstrings.

I cannot see past this and come up with a solution that allows the users machine to encrypt the config file without having an unencrypted version on their machine first.

Is there a solution that allows the users to encrypt the file themselves?

Comment: How is it encrypted and decrypted? You could create a tool that decrypts and encrypts it again (with the users key) and the machine never actually has the unencrypted connectionstring. Example: You have a general encryption, and a tool where the user can enter his encryption key and he gets the connection string encrypted with his key out of it. Just an idea. You can probably read that up on the interwebz.

Comment: Hi @Mafii thanks for your time. I'd like this to happen all in the background when the user signs into my system i.e. all within the C# app if at all possible.

Comment: What or who are you trying to protect against?

Comment: We don't have any particular threats, I just don't want to store the connection information in plain text.

Comment: Can you show us your `configProtectedData` section?

Comment: You should make an installer with a custom action to encrypt the connection string during install. So you have the app.config in plain text in code, but it encrypts on the users machine using their machine key as it gets installed. Probably too large a topic to make an answer for, should be some examples if you google it.